# Data append to the top row of the table

Tags: javascript

how can I append the data to the top row of my table. Here is my code:

```
   $(data).appendTo('#feeds:last');
```

How can I append data to the top row of my table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add an element to the top of a table you can use `prepend()`:

```
$('#feeds').prepend(data);
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/KZ7qc/

jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

If I have misunderstood your question and you really want it to be the last row, then you can just change the above code to append()

Comment: No because that sends it to the top